# Model summary tables for GLMMtmb

Tags: model, glmm, tables

What package do people use to nicely visualize glmm model summaries? I tried huxtable::huxreg as explained [here](https://bbolker.github.io/stat4c03/notes/tidymodels.pdf), but the documentation must be out of date because huxreg does not accept glmmTMB objects. sjPlot::tab_model, as explained [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sjPlot/vignettes/tab_mixed.html), does not output all of the information from the model; it only includes incidence rate ratios, CIs, and p-values. Stargazer doesn't accept glmm objects either. How can I create an html or latex table from a glmmTMB object?

Comment: Any solution found?